# How to configure Xcode to compile not supported language, e.g. Fortran?

Tags: configuration, fortran, xcode6

I would like to use Xcode under Mac OS X to compile and run a program written in a language that is not supported, e.g. Fortran. Assuming I have a compiler installed, e.g. gfortran or ifort, what are the steps in the Xcode project settings to make it possible to compile and run the program?

I have created an new, empty project since Fortran is not supported (only C,C++,Objective-C and Swift are selectable in a command line tool application). I created a simple Fortran file. But now I guess I have to add several things to the Builds tab in the project settings to make it compile and run (it works from the command line). What are these steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an external build system target to your project. External build system targets/projects let you build projects in languages Xcode doesn't natively support. The external build system target/project is in the Other section under OS X on the left side of the assistant. When you click the Next button, you'll be asked for the location of the build tool. Enter the path to your Fortran compiler. When you build the project, Xcode will use the Fortran compiler to do the building.

Comment: I was able to add the external build system but the builds are failing because no file was specified to compile. How do I tell Xcode which files need to be compiled in which order? And how can I specify compiler flags?

Comment: Select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select the target from the project editor. Click the Info button at the top of the editor. Enter your files in the Arguments text field. There's a Build Settings section in the project editor. I don't know if you can place Fortran flags there. If not, you'll have to add the flags to the Arguments text field.

Comment: Great, thanks. The last thing I like to ask is how can I run the program from within Xcode so that the result is displayed in the terminal section?

Comment: Edit the scheme for the project. Select the Run step from the left side of the scheme editor. Choose an executable from the Executable menu. You'll have to build the project to create the executable before you can set the executable for the scheme.